# ld returned 1 exit status, fibonacci search

Tags: c, ld, exitstatus

i think my "dear" code has a problem, i'm using code block and when i try to compile, the compiler show me this error: "ld returned 1 exit status"

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "C:\Users\alexl_000\Desktop\fibmodnopoin\fib.h"

int main(){
    int position;
    int *fib_ptr,fib=2;
    char confirm='y';
    fib_ptr = &fib;

printf("find Fibonacci's number by it's position \n");

while(confirm=='y'){
    printf("insert position:");
    scanf("%d", &position);
    printf("%d \n",position);
    fib=fibonacci(position);
    printf("%d \n", *fib_ptr);
    printf("find new number?");
    scanf("%s", &confirm);
}
return 0;
}
```

fib.h

```
#ifndef FIB_H_INCLUDED
#define FIB_H_INCLUDED
#endif // FIB_H_INCLUDED

int fibonacci(int );
```

fib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int fibonacci(int position){

    int fib1=1, fib2=1, count=3, fib;

    if (posizione==0)
      fib=0;

    else if (position==1||2 )
      fib=1;

    if (position>2){
      while(count <=  position){
         count++;
         fib=fib1+fib2;
         fib2=fib1;
         fib1=fib;
        }
    }
    return fib ;
}
```

compiler

```
||=== Build: Debug in fibmodnopoin (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

before there were a linking problem due to "debug" and "release" box not checked

```
reference not defined to "fibonacci"
```

but i solve it: right click to `fib.c` or\and `fib.h`, properties->build

i really do not find a way to solve the first problem...

Thank you for the attention

Comment: Could you post the compiler command? Are you sure you are compiling fib.c too and then link fib.o to your output?

Comment: Side note: `int fibonacci(int );` should be placed between `#define FIB_H_INCLUDED` and `#endif`

Comment: Probably `fib.o` is not linked.

Comment: I'm using code block on windows with MinGW, i do not use the compiler terminal commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a linker error.
You have provided declaration (prototype) of the function to the main program but the definition is not provided. You need to compile both the file and provide the object files to the linker (ld).
In linux, compile together as follows

> gcc main.c fib.c -o fib

Comment: I'd add `-Wall`, always.

Comment: i use windows and MinGW, but with your command + .exe  at the end of the string it works from the prompt

Comment: @alexioloruxo , it is not a CodeBlock's error. You haven't provided the file additional to compile it seems. Compile fib.c first, then go to linker setting->Other Linker Option add "Path_to_"/fib.o and compile main program. It will work fine.

Comment: @NishanthShetty, i just tried but still not work, same build error

Answer (score 1):

In Fib.c, you're checking a "posizione" variable, which is not declared anywhere. Once you change that, you should be able to rebuild the module and after that, the project.

As a side note, I'd recommend checking the include guard in fib.h. Normally, you'd put declarations in the ifdef block to make sure the variables are only declared once per file.

Comment: it's a typing error, i'm italian and "posizione" is "position"
i rewrite the variables' name in english when i write the  question and i made a little mistake

Answer (score 0):

the code is correct, i used the command prompt and the code

```
gcc main.c fib.c -o fib.exe
```

and it works, so i think it's a CodeBlocks' error. What could be the problem?